# Solving a numeric statistics problem - R

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods

I am quite stuck with solving some complicated numerical equation

I would like to solve the following equation:

$(1-k)\tilde{\alpha}+kf(\tilde{\alpha})=C$

where $0<k<1$ and $f(\tilde{\alpha})$ is a right tail percentage of a multivariate distribution of a length n with the covariance matrix is 1 on the diagonal and n-2/n-1 in all the other entrences and the mu vector equals zero in all n entrances.

then:

$f(\tilde{\alpha})=P(Z_1>z_{1-\tilde{\alpha}},...,Z_n>z_{1-\tilde{\alpha}})$

when $n=\infty$ we get that $\tilde\alpha=C$

generally:

$\tilde{\alpha}^n\leq f(\tilde{\alpha})\leq\tilde{\alpha}$

and $C\leq\tilde{\alpha}\leq1$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it a multivariate *normal* distribution or something else? Please confirm if  $\tilde{\alpha}$ is the unknown? What does $m$ and $\alpha$ represent? Are they simply constant given to you? Do you know how to evaluate $f(\tilde{\alpha})$ or is this the *main* difficulty you are faced with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are basically interested in solving the equation numerically, over all possible $\tilde{\alpha}$. In case you are OK with Python:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin_l_bfgs_b as bfgs
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import mvn
import numpy as np
k = 0.2
c = 0.05
n = 3

def get_z(alpha):
    return norm.ppf(alpha)

def get_sigma():
    sigma = np.ones((n,n))*(n-2)/(n-1)
    return sigma+np.identity(n)*1.0/(n-1)

def get_f(alpha):
    mu = np.zeros(n)
    S = get_sigma()
    low = np.ones(n)*get_z(1-alpha)
    upp = np.ones(n)*1000
    p, i = mvn.mvnun(low, upp, mu, S)
    return p

def g(alpha):
    return (k*alpha + (1-k)*get_f(alpha)-c)**2

def optimize():
    return bfgs(g,0.4,approx_grad=1,bounds=[(0,1.)])

print optimize()
```

This should solve it.